# Jquery - (ajax async:true) element size not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin and in the "**onFinish**" event option I am doing some logic. Nothing too fancy. See below, I have a div which I created in the script called **$message**, I then iterate over a list of radio buttons with class **.daily_persons**. If any one of the radio elements don't meet my condition I append a paragraph tag to the initial div. No problems so far.

The problem is the initial div is used to show a dialogue only if its not empty. I tried lots of things, juqey children, has('p').length; nothings seems to work as `if($message.size()>0)` always evaluates to `1 > 0 = true`

```
onFinish: function() {
    var $message = $('<div title="Sessions Not Available"></div>');                                  

    $('.daily_persons:checked').each(function() {
        var mylimit = 0;
        var $this = $(this);                

        $.get("<?php echo base_url();?>register/chackSessAvaiable",
                { id: $this.val()}, function(data) {
            $this.attr('area') == "biksha" ? mylimit = 3 : mylimit = 10; 
            if (!(data < mylimit)) {                       
                $message.append("<p>"+$this.attr('humandate')+"</p>");
                $this.prop("checked", false);
                $this.prop("disabled", true);
                updateCost();
            }
        });
    }); 

    if ($message.size() > 0) {
        $message.dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 350,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $message.html('');
                }
            }
        });               
    } else {
        alert("proceed");                    
    }   
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: size() is deprectated, better is to use .length property instead. That's said, this is not your issue here. Looks like you want to check if some `<p>` are added to $message DIV. But as you are adding `<p>` tgs in $.get() success callback, you can check it here. Set your logic inside $.get() success callback and then no need to check if $message is empty or not. Because ya, $.get() is async

Comment: Thanks A. Wolff your hint about "$.get() is async" set me along the correct path. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all tha was needed is to make my ajax call **async:false** like this

```
            onFinish: function(){
           var $message = $('<div title="Sessions Not Available"></div>');                                  
            $('.daily_persons:checked').each(function(){
                var mylimit = 0;
                var $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>register/chackSessAvaiable",
                  data: { id: $this.val()},
                  success: function(data){
                    $this.attr('area')=="biksha" ? mylimit = 3 : mylimit = 10; 
                    if(!(data < mylimit)){                       
                        $message.append("<p>"+$this.attr('humandate')+"</p>");
                        $this.prop("checked", false);
                        $this.prop("disabled",true);
                        updateCost();
                    }                    
                  },
                  dataType: "json",
                  async:false
                });                
            }); 
alert($message.children().length);

            }
```